# Consequent styling using selectors in d3 (only the last one takes effect)

Tags: javascript, d3.js

In the following code, I want to change the style of `svg circle` elements when `click` event happens. The problem is that change of `opacity` doesn't take effect  as long as it comes before changing `fill` (only the last change takes effect).

```
node.append("circle")
    .attr("r", function(d) {
        return nodeRadius;
    })
    .style("fill", "steelblue")
    .attr("class", "nodeCircle")
    .style("opacity", function(d) {
        return d.match;
    })
    .attr("id", function(d) {
        return d.id;
    })
    .on("click", function() {
        var neighbors = getNeighbours(this.id);
        d3.select('#' + this.id).style('fill', 'red');
        d3.select('#' + this.id).style('opacity', 1);
        d3.selectAll('.nodeCircle').transition().style('opacity', function() {
            var itrCircle = this;
            return (neighbors.indexOf(itrCircle.id) === -1) ? itrCircle.style.opacity : 1;
        });
        d3.selectAll('.nodeCircle').transition().style('fill', function() {
            var itrCircle = this;
            return (neighbors.indexOf(itrCircle.id) === -1) ? itrCircle.style.fill : 'red';
        });
    });
```

Any idea how to fix this problem and why this happens ?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Creating a transition on a selection cancels any existing transitions. So you're cancelling the first one when you're creating the second. To fix, simply chain the style changes:

```
d3.selectAll('.nodeCircle').transition()
  .style('opacity', function() {
        var itrCircle = this;
        return (neighbors.indexOf(itrCircle.id) === -1) ? itrCircle.style.opacity : 1;
  })
  .style('fill', function() {
        var itrCircle = this;
        return (neighbors.indexOf(itrCircle.id) === -1) ? itrCircle.style.fill : 'red';
  });
```